# HP 530 instalation os issue

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have an old hp 530 laptop and I tried to install to windows xp after it had windows 7.I had some problems in booting the windows so I extracted the hdd and made the setup from another computer and worked perfectly then I connected the hdd back to the laptop and after opening the windows loading bar it restarts.Any advices thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  Boot into Windows XP and start to to through process of elimination determine which driver is causing the problem.

Comment: I have only installed sp3 xp without additional drivers yet for the specific laptop it wont't let me enter windows anyhow and now I pressed F8 to disable automatic restart and says it may be problem with the hdd but it works fine with other pc and worked fine until now btw the same bootable cd has been used for another laptop and worked fine.

Comment: If Windows does not boot and restarts its because of a driver.  Have you tried Safe Mode?

Comment: yes still the same

Comment: I suggest you reinstall Windows on the machine in question.  It being able to boot on another laptop doesn't mean much unless the hardware is exactly the same.

Comment: ok thx very much, I appreciate your help , hope it copes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a repair of the installation, and see if that helps.  But the answers about it being a driver issue are correct.

The most common reason for this is going between Intel & AMD processors.  If this is your issue (other person's system had one, yours has the other), please post back so & I will point you to the procedure for repairing XP in this specific situation.  Since it won't even come up in Safe Mode, I'm just guessing that this is the likely cause, because most device issues won't give the symptoms you describe.